# How to preserve date and datetime format while saving dataframe to csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date

I am using Python to save the data of date and datetime columns in specific format while storing it in a csv file.

However, whenever I open the file in Microsoft Excel the format changes to the default format of Excel.

Is there a way to resolve this while keeping csv as format?

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
import csv

def convert_datetime(cell):
    try:
        if pd.notnull(cell):
            return f"{datetime.strptime(f'{cell}', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}"
        else:
            return None
    except ValueError:
        return cell

def convert_date(cell):
    try:
        if pd.notnull(cell):
            return f"{datetime.strptime(f'{cell}', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
        else:
            return None
    except ValueError:
        return cell

file_name = input("Enter the file name with extension (xlsx or csv): ")

if os.path.exists(file_name):
    file_extension = file_name.split('.')[-1]

    if file_extension == 'xlsx':
        df = pd.read_excel(file_name, engine='openpyxl')
    elif file_extension == 'csv':
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

    datetime_columns = ['created', 'created_date', 'modify_date']
    date_columns = ['offers_expiry']

    for col in date_columns:
        if col in df.columns:
            df[col] = df[col].fillna(pd.Timestamp.now())
            df[col] = df[col].apply(convert_date)

    for col in datetime_columns:
        if col in df.columns:
            df[col] = df[col].fillna(pd.Timestamp.now())
            df[col] = df[col].apply(convert_datetime)
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))

    output_file_name = "modified_" + os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] + '.csv'
    df.to_csv(output_file_name, index=False, header=False)


    print(f"Modified file saved as {output_file_name}")

else:
    print("File not found.")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to resolve this while keeping csv as format?

**Unfortunately not**. If you want to control the output format, you have to export your data as excel to set the format with [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html). Something like:

```
# Read your data
df = pd.DataFrame({'created': ['09/10/2023 07:34:23 AM'], 
                   'offers_expiry': ['09/10/2023']})

# For datetime columns (your function should return DatetimeIndex)
df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created'])

# For date columns (your function should return a Series with date objects)
df['offers_expiry'] = pd.to_datetime(df['offers_expiry']).dt.date

# Export your data
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
    date_format='DD MM YYYY',
    datetime_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS',
    engine='xlsxwriter'
) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

The output respects the date and datetime formats:

[image]